# Criação de gráfico c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde amigos, estou criando um programa em c# que deve plotar em um gráfico os valores atuais da porta serial(arduino) em uma picture box. Para desenhar o gráfico estou criando pontos(x,y) e ligando os mesmos formando linhas (drawline). Desta maneira o gráfico é desenhado, porém a "caneta" que percorre a picturebox. Estou tentando fazer um efeito semelhante à um sismógrafo (como se o papel(picturebox) que deslocasse, como o do vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cSlxPeqHA8). Acredito que seja basicamente deslocar varias linhas. Atualmente, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
int contDRAW = 0, a; //contadores
private PointF[] vetpoint = new PointF[6000];//vetor para incrementar o X para fazer o deslocamento
float[] aquisicaoplot = new float[6000]; //vetor onde armazeno cada valor enviado pela serial

//a cada vez que for chamada a função desenhar já tenho um novo y
private void Desenhar()
        {
            vetpoint[contDRAW].Y = aquisicaoplot[contDRAW];
            for (a = 0; a <= contDRAW; a++)
            {
                if (contDRAW != a)
                {
                    vetpoint[a].X ++;
                }
                else vetpoint[a].X = 0;

                if (contDRAW == 0 || a==0) timerDRAW.Enabled = true;
                else graph.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.LightGreen, 0.1f), vetpoint[a - 1].X, 24 * aquisicaoplot[a-1], vetpoint[a].X, 24 *aquisicaoplot[a]);     
            }
            contDRAW++;
        }

private void timerDRAW_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

Este código chega perto do resultado pretendido. O gráfico atualmente está deslocando, porém ele é resetado e redesenhado toda vez que entra no "for". O que posso fazer? Estou seguindo o caminho certo? Se alguém souber ou tiver alguma dica de como posso fazer esse efeito por favor  responda.

EDIT1:

Atualizei a função Desenhar() para o seguinte:

```
private void Desenhar()
{
    System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen, 0.1f);
    vetpoint[contDRAW].Y = 24*aquisicaoplot[contDRAW];
    for (a = 0; a <= contDRAW; a++)
    {
        if (contDRAW != a) vetpoint[a].X++;
        else vetpoint[a].X = 0;
    }
    if (contDRAW == 0) timerDRAW.Enabled = true;
    else graph.DrawLines(myPen, vetpoint);
    //else graph.DrawLine(myPen, vetpoint[contDRAW - 1].X, 24 * aquisicaoplot[contDRAW-1], vetpoint[contDRAW].X, 24 * aquisicaoplot[contDRAW]);
    contDRAW++;
    myPen.Dispose();
}
```

Tive um pequeno avanço em relação ao efeito que quero produzir, pois o gráfico se movimenta sem ficar redesenhando desde o início, porém, agora está com muito flicker e muito delay depois de desenhar vários pontos.

Comment: O queq o método `Refresh()` faz? Ele foi chamado no método `timerDRAW_Tick` e não foi postado. E onde a função `Desenhar` é chamada?

Comment: A função Desenhar( ) é chamada toda vez que tenho um novo dado na serial. Ou seja, mais um y que deve ser colocado no gráfico. O Refresh( ) seria pra "atualizar" o gráfico com os novos pontos deslocados.

Comment: Toda vez que faço a leitura de um dado da serial eu desenho o novo ponto na coordenada (0,0) e desloco o restante dos pontos pra direita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um controle, vê se lhe ajuda. 
Defina as propriedades MinValue e MaxValue e DataCount - Quantidade de dados que aprarecerão..
Basta criar um timer e chamar o método AddValue a cada tempo.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

public class GraphControl : Control
{
    private int _minValue = -100;
    private int _maxValue = 100;
    private int _dataCount = 25;
    private List<int> _values = new List<int>();

    public int MinValue
    {
        get => _minValue;
        set
        {
            _minValue = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public int MaxValue
    {
        get => _maxValue;
        set
        {
            _maxValue = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public int DataCount
    {
        get => _dataCount;
        set
        {
            _dataCount = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public GraphControl()
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    public void AddValue(int value)
    {
        _values.Add(value);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, 0F, (float)Height * 0.5F, (float)Width, (float)Height * 0.5F);

        var wid = (float)Width / (float)_dataCount;

        for (var i = 0; i < _dataCount; i++)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, wid * i, 0F, wid * i, Height);

        var lastPoint = new PointF(0F, (float)Height * 0.5F);
        var idInit = _values.Count - _dataCount;

        if (idInit < 0)
            idInit = 0;

        for (int i = idInit, a = 0; i < _values.Count; i++, a++)
        {
            var value = (float)(_values[i] - MinValue);
            var total = (float)(MaxValue - MinValue);
            var porcent = value / total;
            var hg = porcent * Height;
            var newPoint = new PointF((a + 1) * wid, Height - hg);

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Maroon, 2))
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint, newPoint);

            lastPoint = newPoint;
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
}
```

Adicione o controle em seu projeto, compile e depois adicione no Windows Forms pelo toolbox.

Exemplo com valores aleatórios:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rd = new Random();
        var num = (rd.Next() % 200) - 100;

        graphControl1.AddValue(num);
    }
```

Comment: você fez alguma alteração do código original? Qual versão .net está usando? Seu aplicativo WindowForms msm ne? O código na versão original funcionou?

Comment: Eu fiz um arquivo de teste e consegui adicionar o control, mas sem resultado algum na execução, só aparece um retângulo cinza, que foi criado no control. Segue o código, estou pegando o 'y' da porta serial.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialCOM.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialCOM_DataReceived);
    graphControl1.AddValue(atualdata);
}
//atualdata é o que estou atualizando com o datareceived

Comment: fiz teste de mesa e o datareceived está funcionando corretamente, o valor desejado é adicionado em 'atualdata'. Porém não é plotado nenhum dado na tela.

Comment: entendi. faz o teste com o código do timer que eu fiz só para teste.

Comment: Talvez seja questão só de mudar o minvalue e o maxvalue do GraphControl, me dê uma lista de valores 10 a 20 mais ou menos que são recebidos pela porta serial para eu fazer o teste.

Comment: sao valores do tipo float de 0 a 5.

Comment: Pq não usa o graphControl1.AddValue() no metodo SerialCOM_DataReceived?

Comment: Cara, aparentemente funcionou aqui, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Salvou muito !!

Comment: blz! qualquer duvida so postar

Comment: Amigo, só mais uma dúvida, o gráfico esta sendo desenhado muito pequeno na tela, gostaria de fazer os 0 à 5 corresponder respectivamente a 0 à 120 de altura. O que posso estar alterando na class controle??

Comment: Consegui amigo, valeu. Ficou muito bom! Único problema é que os valores de _minValue e _maxValue não mudam para o que eu coloco, fica sempre 100 e -100. Comprovei através da inspeção. Ajustei manualmente nos cálculos para determinação do ponto e está funcionando da maneira esperada agora.

Comment: ok. para mudar os valores de 100 e -100 não mude no código. Mude pela properties do controle, como se fosee um outro controle qualquer. Tipo uma TextBox.

Comment: boa tarde amigo, tudo certo? Eu precisava fazer 3  gráficos ao mesmo tempo. Da para usar o mesmo controle?

Comment: sim, pode se usar sim